# Laravel4, provide default RESTful routes with more arguments

Tags: php, rest, laravel, laravel-4

I'm coding a very basic rest api, using

```
Route::resource('foo', 'FooController');
```

so that i can handle any method in my controller. For example, i can list all my foo entities at uri 'foo', handled by

```
public function index() {
    return Response::json(Foo::all()->toArray());
}
```

What if i need api to fetch all Foos **where bar=1** ?

Is this possible **without** coding a custom controller, therefore having to specify every single action (i.e. 'foo/filter/{filterName}/{filterValue}')?

One possible solution i can think of is adding extra parameters in querystring, though i don't really like this approach

Comment: You will have to write an additional route like `Route::get('foo/filter/{filterName}/{filterValue}', array('as' => 'filteredroute', 'uses' => 'FooController@filter') )` . For every additional route you need besides those provided by `Route::resource`. `Route::resource` enables you quick CRUD RESTful access.

Comment: extra parameters in the query string is how a lot (maybe most) allow you to filter results. basically you would provide a list of query strings that you allow them to filter by and add those to your where statement.